# How to stop text moving on hover when changing font-weight?

Tags: html, css

How do you stop the text moving on hover when you change the font-weight?

My standard `<a>` has a `font-weight: 300` then on hover changes to `font-weight: 700` and it this causes the text to move, how do you fix this?

[CODE PEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/ifusion/pen/wMaoMz?editors=110)

```css
    .clearfix:after {
      visibility: hidden;
      display: block;
      font-size: 0;
      content: " ";
      clear: both;
      height: 0;
    }
    
    .clearfix {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    /* start commented backslash hack \*/
    * html .clearfix {
      height: 1%;
    }
    
    .clearfix {
      display: block;
    }
    
    /* close commented backslash hack */
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      background: #c2c2c2;
      font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    }
    ul li {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      border-left: 1px solid #eeeff2;
    }
    ul li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 25px;
      display: block;
      padding: 20px;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    ul li a:hover {
      font-weight: 700;
    }
```

```html
   <ul class="clearfix">
      <li><a href="">Testing 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Testing 2</a> </li>
      <li><a href="">Testing 3</a> </li>
      <li><a href="">Testing 4</a> </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You are changing the size of the text, that is why the text is moving. You could make your containers slightly bigger and you won't notice the text growing as much.

Comment: Ok, whats the best way to stop the text moment whilst still keeping the same on hover effect?

Comment: I think youll have to have a different effect that only changes the color and not the size of the text when you hover over it

Comment: What you are asking for is a [non proportional font](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXbNzy?editors=110). Which is actually not what you want though. Changing the weight of a proportional font does indeed change the size.

Answer (score 4):

Don't change the font-weight or the letter-spacing. (Of course you can style the font just like you want with font-weight and everything, but just don't change it on :hover).

In order to make the text more bold/visible on mouse-over, just add text-shadow to the :hover style. This will not move the text around, but simply add a border around it.

For example:

```
text-shadow: 1px 0 black;
```

or (for a much bolder style):

```
text-shadow: 1px 0 black, -1px 0 black, 0 -1px black, 0 1px black;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is hacky, but since you are changing the total width of the word due to the font getting thicker, you could shorten the spacing between the letters like this

```
a {
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 25px;
            display: block;
            padding: 20px;
            font-weight: 300;

            &:hover {
                font-weight: 700;
                letter-spacing: -.2px;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Like I said though, it is hacky and I am not proud of my answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Since the font weight is being changed, the width of the word increases which causes it to move. Increasing the letter-spacing in the non hovered link will give the desired results.

```
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 25px;
        display: block;
        padding: 20px;
        font-weight: 300;
        letter-spacing: 1.25px;
        &:hover {
            font-weight: 700;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
        }
    }
```